# Order data frame according to values of 2 (or more) vectors for (2 or more) columns

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Trivial question but I did not find any answer.

I am trying to order a data frame based on two columns which should respectively follow two vectors.

Here is an example. I would like to order the column "word" wording to the vector "orderword" and then order the column "replicate" by the vector "orderreplicate".

```
dat<-data.frame(word=c("play","play","play","http", "http","http","offer","offer", "offer","win","win","win"),
               replicate = c("A","B","C","A","B","C","A","B","C","A","B","C"), 
               frequency=c(321,355,123,564,682, 958, 478,459, 215, 48,456,957))

orderword <- c("play", "offer", "win", "http")
orderreplicate <- c("A", "C", "B")

datnew <- dat[match(orderword, dat$word),]
datnew <- dat[match(orderreplicate, dat$replicate),]
```

Even these first basic solutions do not work.
So I tried:

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% arrange(factor(word, levels = orderword))
```

but then I am blocked regarding to the ordering according to orderreplicate.
Do you have any idea? literature about that (if I have more than 2 columns to order)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a scalable solution using `map` to convert to `factor` across multiple columns:

```r
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
cols = c("word", "replicate")
l = list(orderword, orderreplicate)

dat %>% 
  mutate(map_dfc(setNames(seq_along(cols), cols),
                 ~ factor(dat[[cols[.x]]], levels = l[[.x]]))) %>% 
  arrange(!!!cols)
```

output

```r
    word replicate frequency
1   play         A       321
2   play         C       123
3   play         B       355
4  offer         A       478
5  offer         C       215
6  offer         B       459
7    win         A        48
8    win         C       957
9    win         B       456
10  http         A       564
11  http         C       958
12  http         B       682
```

---

Translated to base R:

```r
cols = c("word", "replicate")
l = list(orderword, orderreplicate)

dat[cols] <- lapply(seq_along(cols),
                    function(x) factor(dat[[cols[x]]], levels = l[[x]]))
dat[order(dat$word, dat$replicate), ]
```

---

Another, non-scalable (but more intuitive) solution is to convert to `factor` first (with the ordered levels) and then use `arrange`:

```r
dat %>% 
  mutate(word = factor(word, levels = orderword),
         replicate = factor(replicate, levels = orderreplicate)) %>% 
  arrange(word, replicate)
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you so much for all these possibilities !! I will have to understand them now :D

Comment: @CharlotteS. Among the 23 questions asked, there is only a single acceptance  (although some doesn't have any answers) which could give a signal that majority of the answers in those questions couldn't meet your expectations.   That could potentially discourage others from attempting your question.

Comment: Ohhhh I did not see that I could accept. I saw that I could not grade the answer until recently so I did not think further. But yes, I accept :)